# Inherit config parameters between separate apache vhost definitions

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I've got a set of virtual hosts that need separate vhost definitions for *:80 and *:443. After creating these, I've found that I've got 20-40 configuration parameters that both *:80 and *:443 share; Is there a way to specify these once and have them shared, rather than twice (once in each VirtualHost definition?)

Answer (score 5):

Just create a separate config file fragment containing the shared directives and `Include` it from both virtual host definitions. (Make sure it's placed someplace where Apache won't try to include it by itself, like it would a `.conf` file in a `conf.d` directory.)

Answer (score 0):

## Rewriting in Virtual Hosts

```
#By default, mod_rewrite configuration settings from the main
#server context are not inherited by virtual hosts. 
#To make the main server settings apply to virtual hosts, 
#place the following directives in each <VirtualHost> section:
#
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
#
```